# Encrypting DB primary key for obfuscation on client side

Tags: mysql, security, encryption, web

I'm building a web app and I'd like to **obfuscate the primary keys** of resources the client is viewing in his browser, for **security** reasons.

Here is an example of a primary key (`1001`) exposed in the URL: `https://example.com/orders/1001`

If the primary key is displayed in plain text (number), the user can guess how many resources we have on server, try to open other user's resources (so called FUSK attacks) and other bad things can happen.

To obfuscate the primary key, the most secure way is to add a column to the DB with **crypto-random strings**, associated with each PK, and use those instead of the PK on client side. However, this security comes at a cost:

1) Generating new random string can require **several attempts** due to **collisions** (extremely rare, but not entirely excluded).

2) After **deleting** a row, the **uniqueness** of a new random key cannot be verified (against the deleted row), and also can cause collisions with DB requests that come later after the original row was deleted.

The above problems could be solved by maintaining a separate table pre-populated with random strings, but I don't like the quickly piling up expenses for such a simple task.

How about simply **encrypting the PK with a symmetric key**? There is for example Skipjack encryption method which fits perfectly for 64-bit keys.

The question is, are there any pitfalls of this idea I'm not aware of?

The opponents of the idea say that (unlike the truly random strings) sooner or later the **encryption could be broken** and result in a security leak. Does it seem really probable? AFAIU, symmetric encryption is considered pretty secure. Besides, my resources are additionally protected with user authentication, so the leak of PK isn't very harmful even if it happens.

What's everyone else is using for the primary DB key obfuscation? Is encrypting primary DB key a common practice? Or does everyone use random string mapping?

Comment: This seems like a lot more complexity than it's worth.  I'd just use a UUID column (either *as* the PK, or as an additional column with a unique constraint).  But if your "resources are additionally protected with user authentication, so the leak of PK isn't very harmful even if it happens", why are you looking to do this in the first place?

Comment: I already don't understand the premise. If you do not want to expose the primary key, just don't include it in the url. You can store every relevant information in session variables (which you have for your authentication anyway). Also it sounds like you are planning to change the ids in the database. That is not necessary. If you need the url to tell you which data you require (if it's not clear from e.g. the user login), you can do that by just mapping url-data with e.g. your symmetric key (but this is maybe what you meant anyway, since you proposed a symmetic key and not a hash).

Comment: @Wyzard: UUID is identical to the "random string" approach I mentioned above. The problem is, I want to use the PK because it's auto-incremented and globally unique for my app, but I don't want to expose it directly to clients. For example, if you send a request to a third-party service passing an order ID every day, the third party can guess how many orders you have in a day. Some other bits of information can be extracted from the PK, and it feels more vulnerable than a random or encrypted string.

Comment: @Solarflare: I have to include the resource ID in the client's request, in one way or another. It doesn't matter if I pass it via URL or store it in a cookie. Some bits of information can be exposed by analyzing the PK (see above). I'm not planning to change the ids in the database (why?). Yes, I'd like to use some mapping of PK and obfuscated ID, just wondering what is the best way to do it, and what are the implications of each method.

Comment: You don't *have to* include the id in the request/cookie. You (hopefully) don't do that with the login information either. You can store the id in the same way (if it cannot be derived from the login data, maybe having a "2" in the url mean "2nd order of the current user"). If you *want to* include but obfucscate an id (which shouldn't be the pk anyway, but e.g. the orderid, which the customer knows already) in the url, you can do that using your encryption. For 3rd party services (which could also use a different url), I would still store it in the db (to e.g. prevent code duplication).

Comment: My question boils down to how I should create what you call "order ID" and how do I associate those with the PK in the "orders" table? If "order ID" has to be stored in the DB along with the PK, then it has downsides (see my original post). If I use encryption to derive the "order ID" from PK then what are the security implications, is it a good practice?

Comment: For logins I use stateless JWT cookie that includes user ID, consisting in a random string stored in the DB (the ID is not derivable/reversible from/to PK). But "users" table is much less intensively and concurrently queried than "orders" table, also the security reqs for "users" table is higher, so the cost of storing the random strings in the "users" table is justified.

Comment: No, the orderID is an attribute of your order. It can be equal to or depend (e.g. via the cipher-algorithm) on the primary key, my "should not" is just an opinion (with reasons, but still just my opinion). To choose your orderid, yes, your symmetric blockcipher would by definition work to get unique orderids (if you never change its format). This hides the order count, it's not for security. Url obfuscation can work independently and in addition to that, but is not required. If the login system doesn't prevent access to other accounts, it's a bigger security concern.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypting your primary keys and exposing the encrypted values seems inefficient, and somewhat overkill. If you really want to go down the obfuscation route, perhaps you may be interested in [hashids](http://hashids.org).

However, the more common way to do this is simply to use a [UUID/GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) as your primary key, and use that in URLs. If you are already using numeric primary keys and don't want to change, the you can add a new GUID column that can act as an *alternate key* - you can then add an index on this column and expose these values in your URLs.

GUIDs, and the ability to randomly generate them in the database engine, is built into almost every database system there is.

I would also like to add that you *cannot* rely soley on URL obfuscation for security - you *must* include proper checks to ensure that only correct, authorised users are able to access each ID.

Comment: UUID might work for the purpose. Do I understand correctly that it's generated by SQL UUID() function during INSERT execution? So do I need another SELECT to get the UUID of the last inserted row ID?

Comment: Also, why do you think that a simple encryption like [SkipJack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skipjack_(cipher)) is more of an overkill compared to storing megabytes of UUIDs in the database?

Comment: Encryption has a computational cost, you have to secure your keys, and is very easy to get wrong. GUID/UUID keys, and indeed using alternate keys, are tried and tested methods that any database will support out-of-the-box. And storage is cheap.

Comment: Regarding UUID generation, I haven't worked with MySQL for many years (MySQL and PostgreSQL these days), so it'd be best to check the docs. But in general, yes, the ID is generated by the database during the INSERT (or could instead be generated by the client, but that's more unusual), and you would call some method that would get the last inserted ID for the current transaction

Comment: Is there a guarantee that the UUID will be always unique, relative to both existing records and already deleted records? I mean, most people think it SHOULD be unique and are OK with it, but I want a perfect, bullet-proof, 100% guarantee, no compromise :) For example, imagine a big bunch of UUIDs are generated in exactly the same moment of time. Then there is a chance of collision, isn't it?

Comment: It's guaranteed - the DB handles this transparently for you.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but if I use UUID() SQL function then I need another SELECT to get the generated uuid after INSERT. I hate hitting the DB twice unnecessarily. Or I could generate the UUID on client side, but then the DB does not guarantee uniqueness any more.

Comment: You would normally SELECT the UUID using the same transaction, so still only one round trip to the DB - this is standard stuff, performance is really not an issue with it. An example with MySQL: `SELECT @id := UUID(); INSERT INTO mytable(id, name) VALUES(@id, 'name'); SELECT @id;`

Comment: Good idea! Just a quick question: two SQL statements separated with semicolon are not technically a transaction, even though they are transmitted into the DB in a single batch, are they? I mean, if one of them fails, the whole batch will not be rolled back, right? Or do you mean I should additionally wrap such statements groups in BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT? Sorry I'm a rookie in SQL...

Comment: That's right - it was a just a quick sample, not meant to be correct in all circumstances :)  If you don't have implicit transactions enabled, you need to start them explicitly